# Spark SQL proxy tables with predicate pushdown

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way in Apache Spark to create a Spark SQL *proxy table* that simply proxies to an underlying (custom) data source?

I have a custom data source that supports predicate pushdown by implementing `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.PrunedFilteredScan` and now I would like to use Spark SQL against that data source where filter predicates are passed through (pushed down) to the data source. Registering the data source as an ordinary temporary table (using `sqlContext.read.format("mydatasource").load().createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")`) is not an option as this will ultimately pull all data into Spark.

Comment: _"as this will ultimately pull all data into Spark."_ can you elaborate how you checked that out and/or what made you think that it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither temporary views (`Dataset.createTempView` and `Dataset.createOrReplaceTempView`) nor external tables (`Catalog.createExternalTable` before 2.2, `Catalog.createTable` since 2.2) should *pull all data into Spark*, and all these options support prtedicate pushdowns to the same extent as the underlying source.

Comment: I thought I had observed something different but true, also temporary views seem to push down predicates. Thanks!